# Using bash scripting within a Jenkins pipeline, how do I extract a variable called x and store it in a variable called Header?

Tags: bash, jenkins, unix

I have been using unix commands within Jenkins.

When I run the build is is successful, and there are 5 headers with 5 rows.

I want to extract the output of just one of these rows, and store it in a variable with the same name as the header. For example, store the output called "John" in a variable called "NAME" within my Jenkins pipeline.

So my question is, in Jenkins bash scripting, how do I extract only the value of "NAME" and store it in variable.

This is what I have tried so far

```
export id=`John config -get center.id | tail -2`;echo $id
OUTPUT = $(lukem get database) | lukem .NAME
echo $OUTPUT
```

From this, I was expecting the value of Name (which is John) to be stored in a variable called Name.

Clearly something is missing, but I think I am on the right lines logically

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. You mention a variable called `Name`, but there’s nothing in your code called `Name`, so how would that work? You run a command called `John`, which looks odd. Is there a command with that (strange) name in your `$PATH`? And you never assign anything to `$OUTPUT`. It looks like you try to but spaces around `=` won’t work, and then what is the piping to `lukem` supposed to do? It would make it a lot easier to answer if you could describe your question in more detail, preferably with a [mcve]. Oh, and use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: ‘_there are 5 headers with 5 rows_’ Where? In what format? ‘_I want to extract the output of just one of these rows_’ How do you identify that particular row? ‘_the output called "John"_’ What does that mean? ‘_in a variable called "NAME"_’ A Bash variable?` `NAME` or `Name`, which is it?

Answer (score -1):

A few questions, is the above code block being ran from a bash script? Are you getting an error, and if so what is the error? I believe the problem is with how the variable is defined in bash and that it would want to look like so:

```
export id=`${NAME} config -get center.id | tail -2`;echo $id
OUTPUT=`$(oc get pod) | jq .${NAME}`
echo $OUTPUT
```

(Note the addition of the `${NAME}` to use the NAME variable, the removal of the space after the declaration of `OUTPUT` and the addition of the backticks ` to indicate that the output of the command will get set to the variable.

Comment: Hi, if you need clarification it's better to use a preliminary comment; after will answer more precisely. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you

Comment: Hi @pierpy, I actually intended to do that, however this is a new account and I dont have enough reputation to comment :/ so settled for an answer as thats what I was told to do until I have enough reputation to comment questions etc.